# Data in Front Matter?

Tags: jekyll

I have some Jekyll front matter:

```
---
layout: boilerplate
title: {{ site.data.products.meta_title }}
---
```

But the meta title from data is not output - how can I get it to be outputted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot use liquid variables in front matter because front matter variables are not processed by Liquid.